# Spring security 6 - Handle exceptions with @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

I have migrated to Spring Boot 3 on an application, that is used as an `Oauth2ResourceServer`. I am using custom `AuthenticationManagerResolver` for this.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
  .headers().cacheControl().disable().and()
  .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
  .requestCache().disable()
  .csrf().disable()
  .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
    authorize
      .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
      .requestMatchers("/endpoint1/**", "/endpoint2/**")
      .authenticated();
    }
  )
  .oauth2ResourceServer(rs -> {
    rs.authenticationManagerResolver(multiTenantAuthenticationManagerResolver);
    }
  )
  return http.build();
}
```

The problem is, that any error that happens in the custom authenticationManagerResolver will return status code 401 to the client, with no message whatsoever. The exceptions are not handled in my `@RestControllerAdvice ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. So I tried adding authenticationEntryPoint.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
  .headers().cacheControl().disable().and()
  .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
  .requestCache().disable()
  .csrf().disable()
  .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
    authorize
      .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
      .requestMatchers("/endpoint1/**", "/endpoint2/**")
      .authenticated();
    }
  )
  .oauth2ResourceServer(rs -> {
    rs.authenticationManagerResolver(multiTenantAuthenticationManagerResolver)
      .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }
  )
  return http.build();
}
```

This is what I've found should work:

**CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint**

```java
public class CustomOAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, e);
    }
}
```

However, there are 2 issues with this approach.

1. The exception does not contain the message that was thrown, it is always just the generic one `org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource`
2. There is no default **HandlerExceptionResolver**, but according to examples, there should be. I receive null.

Anyone has any tips on how to propagate the original exceptions to the `@RestControllerAdvice`?

Comment: Spring Security 6 applies authorization to every dispatcher type. I think that is happening because when an error occurs, Spring Boot redirects you to `/error`, which is not authorized, hence the 401. Try doing `http.authorizeHttpRequests().dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()`

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio Now I get 500 instead of 401 but **ControllerAdvice** was not called. The log before event was thrown in the console was `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/app] threw exception`

Comment: @Divanshu I did not fix it yet.